# How do i do while loops in Java?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm new to Java and wanted to learn a few basics about coding.

I got stuck on the while loop! It seems like my compiler is just not executing the loop and I suspect it has something to do with my variables, but I genuinely do not know what to do.

I've already looked through similar problems but none of them could help me so far.

```java
System.out.println("Ist die gesuchte Zahl größer als die angegebene Zahl?");

while (ja) {
    System.out.print("Wir haben die Zahl gefunden!");
}

while (nein) {
    System.out.print("Ist die gesuchte Zahl größer oder kleiner?");
    
    if (kleiner) {
        int nummer2 = 1 + (int)(100 * Math.random()) - nummer;
        System.out.println("Ist " + nummer2 + "die gesuchte Zahl?");
    } else if (größer) {
        int nummer3 = 1 + (int)(100 * Math.random()) + nummer;
        System.out.println("Ist " + nummer3 + "die gesuchte Zahl?");
    }
}
```

Comment: Those variables (`ja`, `nein`, etc) must be of boolean types. Where are they defined?

Comment: This is infinitely better answered by finding a good Java basics tutorial and running through that, as the reason you're having problems is that you may not yet understand the fundamentals of which primitive types do what to be able to even write while loops. A good tutorial (and there are many) will help you along much better than any answer for just this problem will.

Answer (score 1):

In a while cycle you must put a condition. While that condition is true the cycle loop continue.
An easy example should be:

```
int a = 0;
while(a<5){
    System.out.println(a);
    a++;
}
```

This cycle will be executed untill a is lower than 5. Each time that this cycle is executed the variable increase. The output will be:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

So you should place a condition in your while loop that should not be always true (that cause an infinite loop) or always false (that will never execute your code).

Comment: thank you! that makes a lot more sense now

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don´t be discouraged because you might not understand everything at the first instance, this all comes with time and a lot of practice. I will do my best to explain the while loop for you.

A while-loop executes everything inside of the curly braces over and over again until the condition inside the parentheses evaluates to false. If your condition is always true, the loop will continue forever. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int i = 0;
     while(i < 5) {
        System.out.println("Looping...");
        i = i + 1;
     }
}
```

This loop would print "Looping..." five times, since i isn´t smaller than 5 after 5 iterations.

You can basically put any expression inside the parentheses that evaluates to a boolean. I would love to get more specific, but for that, it would be nice to know where your variables `ja` and `nein` are defined.

I would recommend you to go and practice the basics again, here is a good example that I used a while ago:

http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel/

Comment: No problem mate ^^